# if div element is present on page, hide other element

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic web form, I'd like to detect if an element is visible; and if it is hide another element of mine. I have the below attempt, but this is not working stabilily; *i.e. the element isn't always hiding.* A better technique out there?

```
setInterval( myValidateFunction2, 1000);

function myValidateFunction2 () {   
    var inElgbl =  document.getElementById('field_52_116');
    if (typeof(inElgbl) != 'undefined' && inElgbl != null)
    {
        document.getElementById('field_52_24').style.display = "none";
    }   
};
```

---

It is by default `display: none;` but may become `display: block;` if it becomes `display: block;` I would like to `display: none;` my other div elem.

Comment: So I'm seeing a few problems here-- 1) Use `!==` over `!=` 2) comparing to the string `"undefined"` rather than just `undefined`.  Regardless, it would be a lot easier to assist you if you could include your HTML (or some subset of it) as well.

Comment: Doing `inElgbl !== null` in your `if` statement should be enough.

Comment: `inElgbl != null` will be true if and only if `inElgbl` is neither `null` nor `undefined`. The rest of the that **if** clause is redundant.

Comment: Is the element you want to detect just visually hidden from the page, or it doesn't exsists until certain action is made / function run? If its the second, maybe try something like: `if(inElgbl) { ... }`, to check if the element exsists ?

Comment: *" I'd like to detect if an element is visible"* - An element existing and an element being visible are two different things. Your element can exist and not be visible, this will fail when that happens.

Comment: Whoops, updated with more info; sry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Consider an element to be visible if it consumes space in the document. For most purposes, this is exactly what you want.
Try this:

```
setInterval( myValidateFunction2, 1000);

function myValidateFunction2 () {   
    var inElgbl =  document.getElementById('field_52_116');
    if (inElgbl.offsetWidth <= 0 && inElgbl.offsetHeight <= 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('field_52_24').style.display = "none";
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most stable way to do this would be using a [DOM Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and setting it up to watch the document or section of the document that could get the element in question.

In the example below, I'll set up an observer to watch an initially empty `div` and after I've set it up, I'll dynamically add the element we're supposed to be on the lookout for. You'll see that the element does not wind up getting displayed.

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations 
var targetNode = document.getElementById('parent');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
function callback(mutationsList, observer) { 
  // We only need to test to see if node is truthy, which it will be if it exists
  if (document.getElementById('field_52_116')){
    document.getElementById('field_52_24').style.display = "none";
    console.log("Node detected! Removing....");
  } 
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// So, we'll add the node to test
let newNode = document.createElement("div");
newNode.textContent = "I'm here so the other node should be hidden!";
newNode.id = "field_52_116";
targetNode.appendChild(newNode);

// Later, you can stop observing if needed
// observer.disconnect();
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
<div id='field_52_24'>ELement to hide</div>
```